# Method that receives different generic lists doesn't work due to incompatible types

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have created a method that returns me the index of the first occurence of an element in list in this way

```
public int getOccurrenceIndex(ArrayList<Object> list, Object o){
        Object tmp;
        for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
            tmp=list.get(i);
            if(tmp.equals(o)){
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

I want to use this with different arrayList for example with

```
ArrayList<Car> carList, Car c
```

or

```
ArrayList<Person> personList, Person p
```

etc.

without define a separate method for each type

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make that method generic. Also, rather than having `ArrayList` as parameter, use `List`, so that it can work with any implementation of `List`:

```
public <T> int getOccurrenceIndex(List<T> list, T o){
    T tmp;
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
        tmp = list.get(i);
        if(tmp.equals(o)){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

BTW, why do you want to write your own method, instead of using [`ArrayList#indexOf(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29) method?

Comment: thanks, Yes i can use indexOf but since I have to do some other stuff in the same way, I use this as sample to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use java Generics,now you can pass any class as below :

```
public  <T> int getOccurrenceIndex(ArrayList<T> list, T o){
        T tmp;
        for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
            tmp=list.get(i);
            if(tmp.equals(o)){
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```